# Minted bug or misuse?

Tags: minted

Consider the following minted code:

```
\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{ocaml}
  foo |this is escaped| bar
\end{minted}
```

which works as expected, i.e., the escaped text is actually escaped.

However, if we change the language from `ocaml` to `prolog`, then the escaped text is no longer escaped:

```
\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{prolog}
  foo |this is no longer escaped| bar
\end{minted}
```

Is this a minted bug or did I misuse the minted package? I tried several escape characters but nothing worked out for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`minted` uses [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) to do the actual highlighting, and this includes `escapeinside`.  Pygment's implementation of `escapeinside` can be [fragile in some circumstances](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/issues/1118/escapeinside-is-fragile-with-some-lexers), and does not work inside strings or comments.

In the `prolog` case, `foo` is [tokenized as a `String.Atom`](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/src/98fceca1948eed7677fef4e31aeb0c7785531a04/pygments/lexers/prolog.py?at=default), so when the lexer reaches the first `|`, it is in the wrong mode for starting an escape.  In contrast, in the `ocaml` case, `foo` is tokenized as a `Name`, so the lexer interprets `|` as an escape.  Ultimately this comes down to an interaction between the way that Pygments implements `escapeinside`, and the way that the `prolog` lexer works.